# Unity OnTriggerEnter2D hit the ball to floor on high speed doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

When I set the `speed` of Ball = 10 `OnTriggerEnter2D` to test the ball hit on the floor work fine, but when I set the `speed` higher (20), `OnTriggerEnter2D` doesn't work and the ball falls down through the `floor`

My code:

```
void Start () {
  rigiBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  ballLayer = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ball");
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
  if (other.CompareTag(Constants.FLOOR_TAG))
  {
    Debug.Log("FLOOR_TAG");
    if (HitFloor != null)
      HitFloor(this);
  }
}

void FixedUpdate() {
  Vector2 tempVect = Direction;
  tempVect = tempVect.normalized * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
  Vector2 newPos = rigiBody.position + tempVect;
  rigiBody.MovePosition(newPos);

  timer += Time.deltaTime;

  RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(newPos, Direction, Speed * Time.deltaTime * 1.2f, ~(ballLayer));
  if (!hit)
    return;
...
```

Inspector of `Ball` below

[image]

What's wrong with this code?

ps I'm using Unity 2017.1.1f1 Personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of my problem was really close

A couple of lines were added and changed

1. add `[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]` for class `Ball`
2. replace variable `RigiBody` to property

Now everything work well, and balls not fall through the floor on high speed

Code after changes look like this

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))] // Added this code
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
  private Rigidbody2D _rigiBody; 
  public Rigidbody2D RigidBody { //And this property
   get {
     if (_rigiBody  == null)
       _rigiBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        return _rigiBody;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the "Collision Detection" property of rigidbody. It should be "continuous" not "discrete". If you choose discrete value you are telling rigidbody to check collision in discrete time intervals. If you move in a high speed, rigidbody will probably miss collision.

Comment: I tried change mode to Continuous - also the ball falls down through the floor

Answer (score 0):

Set the collision detection mode in the Rigidbody2D component to Continuous. [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CollisionDetectionMode2D.html)

And maybe changing

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(newPos, Direction, Speed * Time.deltaTime * 1.2f, ~(ballLayer));
```

to

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(newPos, Direction, Speed * 1.2f, ~(ballLayer));
```

will fix the problem aswell.

Comment: I just tried it - it doesn't work correctly. Balls fly up. Also tried only change mode to Continuous - also the ball falls down through the floor

Comment: Weird, the balls go up. That shouldn't be the case when changing the distance of the raycast.

maybe you can fix the collision by setting the speed equal to the distance, when the distance is smaller than the speed. by using [Physics2D.Raycast.distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-distance.html)

`if (hit.distance < speed)
            {
                speed = hit.distance);
            }`

Also make sure the collider on your floor isn't set to [isTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you cast the Ray from the newPosition? Imo. You should cast it from its current Position.

Comment: transform.position?